# LINQ ToDictionary initial capacity

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

I regularly use the LINQ extension method ToDictionary, but am wondering about the performance. There is no parameter to define the capacity for the dictionary and with a list of 100k items or more, this could become an issue:

```
IList<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, ... , 1000000 };
IDictionary<int, string> dictionary = list.ToDictionary<int, string>(x => x, x => x.ToString("D7"));
```

Does the implementation actually take the list.Count and passes it to the constructor for the dictionary?
Or is the resizing of the dictionary fast enough, so I don't really have to worry about it?

Comment: Have you tried timing the length of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the implementation actually take the list.Count and passes it to
>   the constructor for the dictionary?

No. According to [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx), the implementation is basically this:

```
Dictionary<TKey, TElement> dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TElement>(comparer);
foreach (TSource current in source)
{
    dictionary.Add(keySelector(current), elementSelector(current));
}
return dictionary;
```

If you **profile** your code and determine that the `ToDictionary` operation is your bottleneck, its trivial to make your own function based on the above code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In that case I'll try with a custom extension to create the dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the implementation actually take the list.Count and passes it to the constructor for the dictionary?

This is an implementation detail and it shouldn't matter to you.

> Or is the resizing of the dictionary fast enough, so I don't really have to worry about it?

Well, I don't know. Only you know whether or not this is actually a bottleneck in your application, and whether or not the performance is acceptable. If you want to know if it's fast enough, write the code and time it. As Eric Lippert is wont to say, if you want to know how fast two horses are, do you pit them in a race against each other, or do you ask random strangers on the Internet which one is faster?

That said, I'm having a really hard time imaging this being a bottleneck in any realistic application. If adding items to a dictionary is a bottleneck in your application, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Normally yes, a call to ToDictionary shouldn't be a bottleneck, but I have to import millions of data and keeps those in dictionaries to create references afterwards. Timing it as Ian suggested would tell me how long it takes, but I was wondering if reimplementing ToDictionary could speed up my application, if I specify the capacity?

Comment: It sounds like you're doing one-time imports? How is that possibly a bottleneck? But, again, my initial point remains. Either it's fast enough as is (your first horse), or it's not and you should code your own version of dictionary (your second horse) and see which of the two horses is fast enough for your purposes. I doubt you're going to see much of a performance difference to begin with, between the two.

Comment: @Franky - I'm pretty sure the dictionary class doubles on every resize, so you're only going to have log2(n) resizes, so in the case of 1,000,000 records, only about 20 resizes. As for the performance on that, I'm not sure, but as akatakritos mentioned, it should be trivial to implement an overload that takes the size.

Comment: While the specification of the capacity, if any, in the ToDictionary() method is indeed an implementation detail, it can be a significant one depending on other implementation details. For instance, we know that List basically doubles its capacity every time the capacity is exceeded. This creates problems when dealing with hundreds of thousands of records, as the capacity of the list can exceed the maximum allowable. If a Dictionary has a similar sizing algorithm for its internal data structure (conceptually a red-black tree, but that can be implemented many ways) then OPs question is valid.

Comment: @Jason - Sadly no. I have to re-import the data twice a day and check against the DB for changes. That's the reason I need to increase the performance as much as I can, because users will still work with the system during the imports.

Comment: @Jason - Run the import in anouther thread? That actually is the case. But in total I have around 2 million objects that I need to save or update. During this whole process, my DB will have mixed data (some tables already updated others not) and I need to reduce the time this takes. This of course is no real bottleneck, but it might be a way to increase the performance.

Comment: @Franky: Goodness. Let the database do the work. Upload the data to a staging table. Join and update or insert as needed. There's plenty of resources on the Internet for how to do bulk updates/inserts. Do that, please!

Comment: @Jason: I would need about 10 staging tables and to be honest, wouldn't know how to do this with NHibernate.

Comment: @Franky: Wait, are you using NHibernate to do the bulk updates/inserts? If so, **THAT IS YOUR BOTTLENECK.** NHibernate is not designed for bulk database operations, it's designed for OLTP. I said at the beginning, and I maintain those statements, I find it nearly impossible to believe that adding items to a dictionary is your bottleneck. You're using the wrong tool for the job that you're trying to do. So what if you need ten staging tables? If performance is genuinely a concern, stop doing it the wrong way. Bulk insert the data into a staging table and do the bulk updates on the database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about resizing the dictionary, but checking the implementation with dotPeek.exe suggests that the implementation does not take the list length.

What the code basically does is:

- create a new dictionary
- iterate over sequence and add items

If you find this a bottleneck, it would be trivial to create your own extension method `ToDictionaryWithCapacity` that works on something that can have its length actually computed without iterating the whole thing.

Just scanned the `Dictionary` implementation. Basically, when it starts to fill up, the internal list is resized by roughly doubling it to a near prime. So that should not happen too frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it'll be a bottleneck TBH. And in case you have real complaints and issues, you should look into it at that time to see if you can improve it, may be you can do paging instead of converting everything at once.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the implementation actually take the list.Count and passes it to the constructor for the dictionary?

It doesn't. That's because the calling Count() would enumerate the source, and then adding it to the dictionary would enumerate the source a second time. It's not a good idea to enumerate the source twice, for example this would fail on DataReaders.

> Or is the resizing of the dictionary fast enough, so I don't really have to worry about it?

The Dictionary.Resize method is used to expand the dictionary. It allocates a new dictionary and copies the existing items into the new dictionary (using Array.Copy). The dictionary size is increased in prime number steps.

This is not the fastest way, but fast enough if you do not know the size.

Comment: `Count` and `Count()` is not the same.

Comment: Leppie, you're right. But ToDictionary() is an extension method for IEnumerable, so Count is not available. Count() is also an extension method for IEnumerable.

Comment: @CarstenSchütte Sometimes the extension methods are optimized for collections that know their `Count` or are indexed. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18200099/543814.