# Is IEnumerable<T>.Last() optimized for List<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a `List<T>`, called `L`, containing N items.

Is `L.Last()`, the `IEnumerable<T>` extension method, going to run through all N items in linear-time?

Or is it internally optimized to have the constant-time performance of `L[L.Count - 1]`?

Comment: Yes. `Last` function is the toffee Wrapper of Loop. No magic inside

Comment: It is optimized for List. You can use L[^1] also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right, if you take a look the code how to implement `Last` (from Reflector):

```
public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null)
    {
        int count = list.Count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            return list[count - 1];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                TSource current;
                do
                {
                    current = enumerator.Current;
                }
                while (enumerator.MoveNext());
                return current;
            }
        }
    }
    throw Error.NoElements();
}
```

It actually optimizes for `List<T>` by returning `list[count - 1];`

Comment: And even if it wasn't optimized in this code, the JIT compiler could potentially optimize the call if it had enough information.

Comment: It's interesting, to me, it wasn't optimized for `ICollection<T>.Count` (given `IList<T> : ICollection<T>`). things that make you go Hmm.

Comment: @BradChristie `ICollection<T>` doesn't have [an indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewthkb10.aspx).

Comment: Exactly what I expected to see in the code. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Touché. You can tell it's getting late for me, and apparently my thought process isn't quite _all there_.

Comment: @PKKG [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) is a paid app, [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) and [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) are two free alternatives.

Comment: You can also check [.Net reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/)

Comment: To @ImadAlazani's question (and @ GKalnytskyi's answer), here is the link to the reference source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,3628defc5be1468a